# How to bridge Windows 8 modern UI with desktop apps?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I'm developing my first app for Windows 8 and I'm stuck deciding between creating a desktop app or a "Modern UI" app (aka Metro app).

My app has no use for the touch-friendly interface of the modern UI but I'm thinking what will be most useful for my user.

If he's on the modern UI all the time, creating a modern UI app with its notifications will be the best thing. However, if the user is a heavy desktop user, that won't matter.

I've noticed that the modern UI apps and the desktop apps live in completely separate worlds. For instance, I logged into the Windows 8 Skype client and went to the desktop. The Skype client was sending me notifications that I was not seeing. Same thing happens with a desktop app, I have not seen any desktop app interact with me while I was using the Start screen or the modern UI apps.

My question is: should I have to choose? What's the best way to bridge those two worlds?

My apps could be used just fine from the modern UI or the desktop. I can't point to anything specific that would tie it to one or another. Even then, I can't decide clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly prohibited from bridging them. A Metro app is not allowed to depend on a desktop app.

> **3.1 You must use only the Windows Runtime APIs to implement the features of your Windows Store app**
>
> We describe these APIs in the Windows Store apps API reference. Your
>   app may only depend on software listed in the Windows Store.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could create two apps: a desktop one and a Windows Store one, and let the user decide which one he wants to use.

With the proper approach you could share a lot of code between the two apps and only implement separately the parts that are platform (i.e. desktop or Windows Store) specific, such as UI, notifications etc. Take a look at [portable class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391.aspx).